# xPages Bootstrap Dojo Progress Bar showing behind modal-backdrop

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, dojo, bootstrap-modal, xpages

I am working on Notes 10. I have a csjs function that calls a dojo progress bar when a full update on an event runs.

It worked perfectly when I used the default theme. However, when I changed the theme to Bootstrap3 the progress bar still displays but it displays behind the bootstrap modal backdrop. I have tried changing the style for .modal-backdrop to display:none or background-color: transparent but nothing took.

Code Below

> Xpage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/xProgress.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.Dialog"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.ProgressBar"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:button value="Test Progress Bar" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" onComplete="progressDlg.hide();">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    print("TEST");
}}]]></xp:this.action>
<xp:this.script><![CDATA[  var progressBar = new dijit.ProgressBar({indeterminate:true, layoutAlign: "left"});

progressDlg = new dijit.Dialog( {
    title:"Please wait... "+"\n" +"Fetching Information.", 
    content: progressBar,
     style: "width: 300px",
     closable: false            //Take this out to show close button
     });
progressDlg.show();]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

> xProgress.js

```
dojo.require("dijit.ProgressBar");

var xProgress= {
    updateInterval : 750,       //update interval in ms
        
    progressXAgentPath : window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf(".nsf")+4) + "/getProgress.xsp",
    
    timerId : null,
    targetNode : null,
    targetNodeId : null,
    progressBar : null,
    
    start : function() {
        this.targetNode = dojo.byId(this.targetNodeId);
        
        if (this.targetNode==0) {
            alert("Invalid target node specified for xProgress progress bar");
        }
        //setup the dijit progressbar
        if (this.progressBar == null) {
            this.progressBar = new dijit.ProgressBar({id: "myProgressBar",  maximum: 100}, this.targetNode);
        } else {
            this.progressBar.update({
                maximum: 100,
                progress: 0
            });
        }
            
        this.timerId = setInterval( dojo.hitch(xProgress, "update"), this.updateInterval);
    },
    
    stop : function() {
        if (this.timerId != null) {
            clearInterval(this.timerId);
            this.timerId = null;
        }
            
        this.progressBar.update({
            progress: 100
        }); 
    },
    
    update : function() {
        dojo.xhrGet({
            url: this.progressXAgentPath,
            handleAs: "json",
            load: dojo.hitch(xProgress, "dataLoadSuccess"),
            error: dojo.hitch(xProgress, "dataLoadError")
        });
    },
    
    dataLoadSuccess : function(data) {
        this.progressBar.update({
            progress: data.progress
        });     
    },
    
    dataLoadError : function(error) {
        this.targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
    }
}

function updateProgress(to) {
    progressPercentage = to;
    sessionScope.put("progress", to);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps changing z-index of the element so it's higher than the modal backdrop.

Comment: @FredrikNorling I have tried changing the z-index but it did not come in front of the backdrop.

Comment: Any site that is public that we can check or a simple .nsf database showing the problem that I can download and check.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The entire notes system is hosted on our server with no public access allowed. But if you replicate my code above in any notes 10 .nsf database you will be able to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the z-index of progressDlg:

```
progressDlg = new dijit.Dialog( {
    title:"Please wait... "+"\n" +"Fetching Information.", 
    content: progressBar,
     style: "width: 300px, z-index: 20000",
     closable: false            //Take this out to show close button
     });
```

**Update:**

The z-index is set to 950 by dijit.Dialog, so setting the z-index in the dijit.Dialog style as proposed above doesn't work.

Try adding CSS for dijitProgressBar:

```
.dijitProgressBar {
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

Comment: I have tried changing the z-index but it did not bring the dialog to in front of the modal backdrop.

Comment: Have you checked the z-index value of the blocking div?  The value may need to be higher.

Comment: What do you mean by blocking div?

Comment: From your browser, go into inspection mode (Ctrl-Shift-i), Elements tab, and identify the <div> containers for the dialog box that is blocking the progress bar.  Check the CSS styles for the z-index value of the 2 elements.  Make the progress bar z-index higher than the other dialog box.

Comment: I've checked the z-index of the dialog box - it's 950.  Try setting the z-index for .dijitProgressBar (I've updated my answer above).

Comment: Have added the styling to my stylesheet and no changes. The dialog has not moved.